# Capitalization of questions in sentences

Tags: capitalization

Which of the following are correct:

"Tom, do you like fishing?"

"Tom, Do you like fishing?"

Comment: [There are a big bunch of rules about when to capitalize things in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization_in_English), but the most important one in this case is *capitalize the first word of a sentence, including if it's reported speech.*  Since "do" isn't the first word of the sentence, don't capitalize it.

Answer (score 1):

Since your example is a single sentence, your first example

> Tom, do you like fishing?

is correct, if you reformulated your second example

> Tom asked, "Do you like fishing?"

Capitalisation can be a question of style, but usually capitalisation occurs at the beginning of sentences and proper names.

> **T**his is an example sentence.
>   **T**he **K**ingdom of **F**eedonia

It can also begin in an embedded quote within a sentence (your second example)

> William asked "**W**here are we?"

Comment: ...and commas usually occur with dialogue tags :D (i.e., William asked(comma)).